# Looking to convert date after doing a split

Tags: javascript

I am looking to convert a date from `MM/DD/YY` to `YYYYMMDD`

The code below gives me an output of 2211 which is incorrect. How can I do a check on Month and Day and add a 0 in front when needed?

```
var arr = '1/1/22';
arr = NTE.split('/');  //splits the date where it sees /
log.debug("Splitting date : "+ arr);
        
longDate=arr[2]+arr[0]+arr[1];   
log.debug("Long Date : "+ longDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like this:

```
let arr = '1/1/22';
arr = arr.split('/');  //splits the date where it sees /
log.debug("Splitting date : "+ arr);

arr = arr.map((element) => element.length > 1 ? element : `0${element}`); // prepend with 0 if needed
const longDate=`20${arr[2]}${arr[0]}${arr[1]}` //prepend year with 20 to convert YY to YYYY
log.debug("Long Date : "+ longDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = '1/1/22';

arr = NTE.split('/');  //splits the date where it sees /
log.debug("Splitting date : "+ arr);
        

if(arr[0]<10){
    var arr0="0"+arr[0];
    log.debug("arr[0]: "+ arr[0]);
    log.debug("add zero to month: "+ arr0);
    var dayEdited = true;
} else {
    dayEdited = false;
}

if(arr[1]<10){
    var arr1="0"+arr[1];
    log.debug("arr[1]: "+ arr[1]);
    log.debug("add zero to day: "+ arr1);
    var monthEdited = true;
} else {
    monthEdited = false;
}


if(arr[2]<2000){
    var arr2="20"+arr[2];
    log.debug("add 20 to Year: "+ arr2);
    var yearEdited = true;      
} else {
    yearEdited = false;
}

if(yearEdited == true & monthEdited == true & dayEdited == true){
    var longerDate=arr2+arr0+arr1+"000000";    //rearrenges the array by YEAR,    MONTH, DAY
    log.debug("Longer Date : "+ longerDate);
} else if(yearEdited == false & monthEdited == true & dayEdited == true){
    var longerDate=arr[2]+arr0+arr1+"000000";    //rearrenges the array by YEAR, MONTH, DAY
    log.debug("Longer Date : "+ longerDate);
} else if(yearEdited == false & monthEdited == false & dayEdited == true){
    var longerDate=arr[2]+arr[0]+arr1+"000000";    //rearrenges the array by YEAR, MONTH, DAY
    log.debug("Longer Date : "+ longerDate);
} else if(yearEdited == false & monthEdited == true & dayEdited == false){
    var longerDate=arr[2]+arr0+arr[1]+"000000";    //rearrenges the array by YEAR, MONTH, DAY
    log.debug("Longer Date : "+ longerDate);    
} else if(yearEdited == true & monthEdited == false & dayEdited == false){
    var longerDate=arr2+arr[0]+arr[1]+"000000";    //rearrenges the array by YEAR, MONTH, DAY
    log.debug("Longer Date : "+ longerDate);
} else if(yearEdited == false & monthEdited == false & dayEdited == false){
    var longerDate=arr[2]+arr[0]+arr[1]+"000000";    //rearrenges the array by YEAR, MONTH, DAY
    log.debug("Longer Date : "+ longerDate);
}
```